# How to return list for the following type "List<List>" having an another object added to this list

Tags: java, generics

I am learning JDBC concept where the problem has occurred while trying to return `List`. I cannot have Invoice list and the type has to be `List`. Kindly help me.The following error has occurred "The method `add(List)` in the type `List<List>` is not applicable for the arguments (`Invoice`)"

```
List<List> invoiceGroupByCustomer() throws SQLException {
        List<List> list = new ArrayList<List>();
        String query1 = "select customer_name,sum(total_amount),sum(balance) from invoice GROUP BY customer_name ORDER BY customer_name";
        try
        {
            DbConnection obj = new DbConnection();
            Connection con = obj.getConnection(); 
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query1);
            while(rs.next())
            {   
                Invoice invoiceobj = new Invoice();
                invoiceobj.setCustomerName(rs.getString("customer_name"));
                invoiceobj.setTotalAmount(rs.getDouble("sum(total_amount)"));
                invoiceobj.setBalance(rs.getDouble("sum(balance)"));    
                list.add(invoiceobj);
            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;

    }
```

Comment: You're trying to add an Invoice object to your List of Lists; The only thing you can add to a List of Lists is a List. It's not clear if you want help adding a List to the list of Lists or if you want to know how to change the type of the List to a List of Invoices

Comment: Note that `List<List>` is a legal but completely useless type. The inner `List` is a raw type, and if you're going to use raw types, you might as well abandon generics entirely. If you really want a list of lists of unknown type, use `List<List<?>>`. But I suspect the type you really want is just `List<Invoice>`.

Comment: I find the question [unclear](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion) just as Charlie said. I also don't see any evidence of [research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) - there is a lot of documentation on Java Generics.

Comment: I suggest you read up on generics, what they are and how they're used. I strongly suspect that you actually meant `List<Invoice>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List> list = new ArrayList<List>();
```

You have to put "List object" in every index of list because you have the list of lists.

Replace the line

```
list.add(invoiceobj);
```

with

```
list.add(Arrays.asList(invoiceobj));
```

Hope it will work.

Or You can can change the method return type from `List<List>` to `List` and return the same object.